# Load X509 Certificate From MySQL BLOB

Tags: c++, import, openssl, x509

I stored a x509 Certificate as BLOB in MySQL. I want to import that certificate now into c++ using the openssl lib.

i figured to use this function

```
X509 *parsedCert = d2i_X509_bio(bio_in, 0);
```

Problem is i need a Pointer to a BIO struct. Because i did not store the certificate into a file, i can only use

```
BIO* BIO_new_mem_buf( void* buf, int length);
```

to retreive my BIO Pointer. Because MySQL gives me the BLOB stored certificate as istream, i tried

```
istream* cert = res->getBlob("cert");
string certs = streamToString(*cert);
BIO *bio_in = BIO_new_mem_buf( const_cast<char*>(certs.c_str()), -1 );
X509 *parsedCert = d2i_X509_bio(bio_in, 0);
```

Unfortunately parsedCert is a Nullpointer. I get the following SSL Errors:

```
SSL ERROR: error:0D06B08E:asn1 encoding routines:func(107):reason(142)
```

My Question is: Is there a way to directly load a x509 certificate from istream to OpenSSL X509 structure?

Comment: I think the blob will be binary, so that setting length to -1 will not work because the string is not terminated with \0. You need to explicitly give the length of the data

Comment: But string.c_str() creates a null terminated c-string, doesn't it?

Comment: yes,but there might be more \0 inside the string before the end, e.g. "foo\0bar" will cause it to calculate a length of 3 even if the length is 7.

Comment: Well... thank you, i am really ashamed that this was the error :( sorry for asking such a trivial question